# How can I read in a subset of an Apache Arrow database's batches?

Tags: apache-arrow

I'm working with a large (20+ GB) Apache Arrow database where I need to efficiently fetch small sets of batches for arbitrary queries that a user might make. Given the indexes of some batches, how can I fetch columns for just those batches without reading in all the other ones too?